# How do I calculate the quartiles for this problem?

Tags: statistics

I have the following list of numbers, and I'm trying to calculate the quartiles:

2, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9

I'm running into a bit of confusion because the median turns out to be 7. Now I don't know how to demarcate the lower group from the upper group since there are a whole bunch of 7's. Consequently, I don't know how to calculate $Q_1$ and $Q_3$.

Comment: There is some confusion between the answers by EpicGuy and Sim. My source agrees with the former, while the quartiles calculator at http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/quartiles/ agrees with the latter. I would appreciate it if someone could resolve this.

Comment: I also had the same problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789135/problems-in-quartiles

Answer (score 0):

So the formula to calculate Quartiles is

Q1 = [image]

and

Q3 = [image]

So our `n = 16`

Hence we have 16+1 = 17*.25 = 4.25

4.25 places along the set of numbers is somewhere inbetween here 5 and 7

so if we split the numbers between 5 and 7 into 4 pieces i.e.

`5`  `5.5`  `6`  `6.5`  `7`

We can calculate `.25` or `1/4` along the way of our little number line we just created is 5.5

Hence `Q1 = 5.5`, with this method you should be able to find `Q3` which is `8.75`

Comment: Your answer doesn't agree with the other answer posted by EpicGuy. It also doesn't agree with my original source from where I took the problem. I like your method, but the other answer is the correct one. I'd like to know how to get the correct answer using this method. Could you please double-check this? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I am the OP. I was finally able to log into my own account.

Comment: @Joebevo You can use a calculator to check if you like here http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/quartiles/

i.e. the answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

you just divide the list into quarters.

First divide into half...
2 4 4 5 7 7 7 7|7 7 8 8 9 9 9 9

Then quarters...
2 4 4 5|7 7 7 7|7 7 8 8|9 9 9 9

So Q1 is average of 5 and 7 which is 6, and Q2 is average of 8 and 9 which is 8.5