# How does Excel calculate quartiles?

Tags: statistics, median

I have the data set `[3,7,9,10]`.

Excel and Desmos both return the value `8` for the median, which agrees with my understanding of how medians are calculated. Since there are four values, the median is calculated as the mean of the middle two: $\frac{7+9}{2}=8$.

My understanding of the first quartile is that it is the median of the lower half of the data. Which would be the mean of $3$ and $7$, so it should be $5$.

Desmos returns `5` as the first quartile, however Excel returns `6` as the first quartile. I'm using the formula `quartile({3,7,9,10},1)`. Similarly Excel gives `9.25` as the third quartile.

What is Excel doing? I have seen in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/489340) that a formula for the first quartile is $\frac{1}{4}\cdot(n+1)$, which means I would be looking for the $\frac{5}{4}=1.25^{th}$ data value. However, wouldn't that make the first quartile be $4$ rather than $6$?

Comment: It looks like it is using $(n-1)/4=0.75$ for the first quantile, and $3(n-1)/4=2.25$ for the third quantile, with zero indexing, so that `3` is the $0$th entry, `7` is the $1$st entry, etc.  There are answers to this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/343339/excel-quartile-function-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a single way of calculating [quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile).

This is a table of quantiles using the nine different methods from your data, using R:

```
type   0%   25%     50%  75%      100%
 1      3    3       7    9        10
 2      3    5       8    9.5      10
 3      3    3       7    9        10
 4      3    3       7    9        10
 5      3    5       8    9.5      10
 6      3    4       8    9.75     10
 7      3    6       8    9.25     10
 8      3    4.6667  8    9.5833   10
 9      3    4.75    8    9.5625   10
```

From the look of it, your Excel calculation seems to be type 7, while your Desmos calculation seems to be type 2 (testing a different case shows it may not be type 5). Types 1 and 3 only take values from the input data while type 2 sometimes averages two consecutive values; the other types attempt to interpolate so as to estimate the population quantile from the sample data.

Comment: Oh my. Nine different types! Maybe the comment Joe left is the formula for type 7? I would need to look at some other data sets to fully understand the differences between the types that gave the same answer for my four values.

Comment: @DreiCleaner It may be more enlightening if you use $4,5,6,7$ different values